# how to create Regex to start with specific multi line tags XML java

Tags: java, regex, xml

my code

```
 Pattern pattern3 = Pattern.compile("^  </build>\r\n" + 
                        "\r\n" + 
                        "   <dependencies>.*</dependencies>\r\n" + 
                        "</project>$", Pattern.DOTALL);

    
List<String> newLines2 = new ArrayList<String>();
             for (String line : Files.readAllLines(c2, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
                 Matcher matcher1 = pattern3.matcher(line);
                 if (matcher.find()) {
                    log.info("found");
                        newLines2.add(matcher1.group());
                      //  matcher.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
                    }
             }
             Files.write(c3, newLines2, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

this is some of my pom.xml dependencies

```
.............
</plugins>



</build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test.tm</groupId>
            <artifactId>password</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For Compress JS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yahoo.platform.yui</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sybase</groupId>
            <artifactId>EccpressoFIPSJca</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sybase</groupId>
            <artifactId>EccpressoFIPS</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
              .......
        <dependency>
              <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
              <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
              <version>6.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

im trying to make regex to extract all theses dependencies starting with the  eg :

```
Pattern pattern3 = Pattern.compile("^   </build>\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "   <dependencies>.*", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Since there are other dependencies tags that exists which im not intrested in also has to end with

```
</dependencies>\r\n" + 
                "</project>$", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

as this is the last tag. Anyway i can do this ^ with my desired `</build>` followed by `<dependencies>` in the next line as this is not getting me any matches for the regex?

Comment: [Don't use regex to parse XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/18157). XML is not a regular language.

Comment: @JimGarrison easy to close this question but this not an answer ^^ if u can close this question provide an answer with code not just text explaining why as im stuck on this issue for 3 weeks and i need a solution to retrieve all the info as mentioned in quesion